# How does this function work? char* getname(); C++

Tags: c++, function, dereference

I'm starting out on how to code in c++.
I've been reading c++ primer plus (5th edition) book and came across an example program which I don't fully understand. Basically, the program asks for your last name and gives you the address of where it gets stored:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
char* getname();
int main();
{
  char* name;
  name = getname();
  cout << name << " at " << (int*)name << endl;
  delete [] name;

  name = getname();
  cout << name << " at " << (int*)name << endl;
  delete [] name;

  return 0;
}

char* getname()
{
  char temp[80];
  cout << "Enter last name: ";
  cin >> temp;
  char* pn = new char [strlen(temp)+1];
  strcpy(pn, temp);

  return pn;
}
```

I don't quite get why char* getname() function needs the dereference operator. I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding this program overall, hehe.
Sorry if this comes across like a silly question, but I'm quite stuck. That's all. Thank you!..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Which _derefeencing operator_? There is no dereferencing all a long.

Comment: It is not `*getname()` with return type `char`. Instead, it is `getname()` with return type `char*`. Google "C type declaration" for more information (the first result is pretty good).

Comment: You should probably refer to the chapter that explains pointers in C...

Comment: @ArthurTacca That helped a lot! It's all clear now, thank you, man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` - it's a pointer to first char in sequence.
`std::cout` with `<<` - has different behavior depending on what you give him.

- If its pointer to first char in sequence (`char* name`) - `cout` printing this sequence.
- If    its pointer to `int` number - `cout` printing address of this number in memory (**0x1105010**)

`(int*)` - casting to pointer to `int`.